# Custom maps in Android, loading via tiles (alternative for RouteMe for iPhone SDK)

Tags: android, ios, maps

I am working on a prototype port of one of our iPhone apps to Android.

The iPhone app uses the RouteMe API to load our own custom maps into the application. (also tiled, just like Google Maps itself, so only loading what you see at that moment - this is very important in this case)

I have been searching for a similar product for Android. I found Nutiteq, but as RouteMe is free, I am trying to find something free for Android as well.

If anybody has suggestions, I would love to hear them. The more information the better, of course :).

EDIT:
Still haven't found anything that acts the same as RouteMe, so suggestions are still very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get away with the standard [MapView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) and Overlays?

Comment: Hmm.. is it possible to use custom maps in the standard MapView?

Comment: Actually that was a quick shot ... you can draw almost anything in the overlays ... but for your needs that won't work.
Alternativly you could have a look at http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/ . They aim to provide a free/open alternative to MapView and i'd guess they have pluggable sources.

Comment: Thank you. A so before you ment I could use my custom map as an overlay item? Hm didn't think of it that way yet.. Although I think it might give some complications later on. I will look some more into osmdroid, I have seen it when searching before posting here, but I couldn't easily find if I could actually use my own maps so moved on for the time being.